# How to transform observable based on predicate involving first element

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-streams, rx.net

I'm trying to create an Rx.NET operator that takes an `Observable<string>` and:

- Forwards each element unchanged if the first element is `"a"`
- Emits just a completion signal otherwise

For example:

`-a-b-c-d-|-  -->  -a-b-c-d-|-`

`-b-c-d-|-  -->  -|-`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version that definately doesn't have a race condition:

```
public static IObservable<T> IfFirstElement<T>(this IObservable<T> source, T expectedFirstElement) =>
    source
        .Publish(published =>
            from x in published.Take(1)
            from y in
                x.Equals(expectedFirstElement)
                ? published.StartWith(x)
                : Observable.Empty<T>()
            select y);
```

---

There's the method syntax version:

```
public static IObservable<T> IfFirstElement<T>(this IObservable<T> source, T expectedFirstElement) =>
    source
        .Publish(published =>
            published
                .Take(1)
                .SelectMany(x =>
                    x.Equals(expectedFirstElement)
                    ? published.StartWith(x)
                    : Observable.Empty<T>()));
```

I prefer the query syntax, but hey...

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any chance that the output sequence will include `expectedFirstElement` twice at the start (perhaps because the `published` observable on line 7 receives the notification of the first element a bit late or something)? Or is this impossible?

Comment: This looks like a good implementation. The query syntax makes it less readable IMHO, but this is just personal preference.

Comment: @jackdry - No, it is impossible. Since the `x` has already been taken from the `published.Take(1)` before the `published.StartWith(x)` has been subscribed to it can't happen. Even better, Rx guarantees that the next element isn't missed either if it comes immediately after the first.

Comment: Thanks for the explantion. Is there anywhere I could read more about the guarantees Rx offers? Or do they not have any documenation on that?

Comment: Upvoted for the method syntax version. 

Comment: @jackdry - I'm not sure where to send you for that. There's plenty of stuff online. It's really that an observable returns zero or more values followed optionally by either a single complete or error message and no two message will overlap.

Comment: @jackdry [The Observable Contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) contains the basic stuff, and there is also the old but good [Rx Design Guidelines](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219) document that goes much deeper (dowloadable PDF). And then there are the innumerable undocumented nuances that make the Rx library so difficult to learn.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - ...but such a powerful tool.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
/// <summary>
/// If the first element has the expected value, return the whole sequence.
/// Otherwise, return an empty sequence.
/// </summary>
public static IObservable<T> IfFirstElement<T>(this IObservable<T> source,
    T expectedFirstElement, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = default)
{
    comparer ??= EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    return source.Publish(published =>
        published
            .Where(x => !comparer.Equals(x, expectedFirstElement))
            .Take(1)
            .IgnoreElements()
            .Amb(published)
    );
}
```

This implementation uses the [`Amb`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211783(v=vs.103)) operator (short for “ambiguous”), which takes two sequences and propagates the sequence that reacts first.

1. If the first element has the desirable value, the first sequence (the `published.Where`+`Take`+`IgnoreElements`) does not react, so the second sequence is propagated (the `published`, which is the whole sequence). At this point the first sequence is unsubscribed, so the `comparer.Equals` method will not be invoked for subsequent elements.
2. If the first element has not the desirable value, the first sequence emits a completion notification, which is propagated by the `Amb` operator, and the second sequence (the whole sequence) is ignored.

Usage example:

```
IObservable<string> original = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" }.ToObservable();
IObservable<string> transformed = original.IfFirstElement("a");
```

---

**Note:** This implementation is based on the assumption that when both sequences react at the same time, the `Amb` operator selects consistently the first sequence. This is not mentioned in the documentation, which states only that *"The `Amb` operator uses parallel processing to detect which sequence yields the first item"*. The [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable/Amb.cs) is quite complex, so I can't derive this guarantee by reading it. If you want something more reliable, you could try this implementation instead:

```
return Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
{
    bool first = true;
    return source.Subscribe(item =>
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
            if (!comparer.Equals(item, expectedFirstElement))
            {
                observer.OnCompleted(); return;
            }
        }
        observer.OnNext(item);
    }, observer.OnError, observer.OnCompleted);
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `Amb` like that, but it works because of the publish. I'd also avoid `Create` as it can introduce race conditions.

Comment: @Enigmativity could you describe a scenario that would cause a race condition in the `Observable.Create` implementation above?

Comment: I just mean in general with `Create`. I just avoid it because it can block, depending on the scheduler used. I've pretty much found that using the regular operators results in observables that behave properly.

Comment: @Enigmativity ah, OK. I asked because someone could read your comment, and conclude that the above implementation is flawed.