# How to propagate an observable sequence, but only if it starts with a specific collection of values?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

This is a "just for fun" question, that extends and generalizes [a recent Rx question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69827701/how-to-transform-observable-based-on-predicate-involving-first-element) by jackdry. The problem here is how to implement an Rx operator that takes an `IObservable<T>` and:

1. Forwards each element unchanged if the first elements of the sequence are equal and in the same order with the elements in a given collection (`ICollection<T>`).
2. Emits an empty sequence otherwise.

For example given the collection of values [a, b, c]:

```
Source sequence: +--a---b----c-----d--e----|
Expected result: +-----------abc---d--e----|
```

```
Source sequence: +----a---p----q---r-----|
Expected result: +--------|
```

```
Source sequence: +------a------b------|
Expected result: +--------------------|
```

```
Source sequence: +---c---a----b--c---d---|
Expected result: +---|
```

The signature of the requested operator:

```
public static IObservable<T> IfFirstElements<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source,
    ICollection<T> expectedFirstElements,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = default);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public static IObservable<T> IfFirstElements<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source,
    ICollection<T> expectedFirstElements,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = default) =>
source
    .Publish(published =>
        from xs in published.Take(expectedFirstElements.Count).ToArray()
        from y in
            xs.SequenceEqual(expectedFirstElements, comparer)
            ? xs.ToObservable(Scheduler.Immediate).Concat(published)
            : Observable.Empty<T>()
        select y);
```

I was trying to make it more efficient by failing early, but every attempt made  it less efficient.

Here's my test code:

```
new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
    .ToObservable()
    .IfFirstElements(new[] { 1, 2, 3 })
    .Dump();

Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
    .Take(7)
    .Select(x => x + 1)
    .IfFirstElements(new long[] { 1, 2, 3 })
    .Dump();

new[] { 2, 2, 3, 4 }
    .ToObservable()
    .IfFirstElements(new[] { 1, 2, 3 })
    .Dump();
```

LINQPad is requried to run the above code to get this output:

[image: output]

---

It's a little harder to get it to end early, but here it is:

```
public static IObservable<T> IfFirstElements<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source,
    ICollection<T> expectedFirstElements,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = default) =>
        source
            .Publish(published =>
                from xs in
                    published
                        .Scan(ImmutableList.Create<T>(), (a, b) => a.Add(b))
                        .TakeUntil(a => a.Zip(expectedFirstElements, (m, n) => comparer == null ? m.Equals(n) : comparer.Equals(m, n)).Any(c => !c))
                        .Take(expectedFirstElements.Count)
                        .LastAsync()
                from y in
                    xs.SequenceEqual(expectedFirstElements, comparer)
                    ? xs.ToObservable(Scheduler.Immediate).Concat(published)
                    : Observable.Empty<T>()
                select y);
```

Comment: Nice! Not the most efficient (it's a O(n²) algorithm), but gets the job done.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - It's only `O(n²)` on the `ICollection<T>`. Hopefully that's not too painful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. This one is similar to Enigmativity's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69846833/11178549), and uses pretty much the same operators. The difference is that when the `source` sequence emits an element, only this element is checked for equality with the corresponding element of the `expectedFirstElements` collection, making it an O(n) algorithm.

```
/// <summary>
/// If the first elements have the expected values, return the whole sequence.
/// Otherwise, return an empty sequence.
/// </summary>
public static IObservable<T> IfFirstElements<T>(this IObservable<T> source,
    ICollection<T> expectedFirstElements, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = default)
{
    comparer ??= EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    return source.Publish(published => published
        .Zip(expectedFirstElements)
        .TakeWhile(e => comparer.Equals(e.First, e.Second))
        .Take(expectedFirstElements.Count)
        .Select(e => e.First)
        .ToList()
        .SelectMany(list => list.Count == expectedFirstElements.Count ?
            published.StartWith(list) : Observable.Empty<T>()));
}
```

As a side note, my initial intention was to have an `IEnumerable<T>` as the container of the expected values. I couldn't find a solution though that doesn't materialize eagerly the enumerable, so I cheated and adapted the problem to the solution I had in hand.  Hence the type of the container being an `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: Btw while I was writing this answer I discovered a surprising behavioral difference between the `Concat` and the `Merge(1)` operators. I opened an issue on GitHub about it [here](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/1634).